# What is monad analog in Java?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I know in Scala and many other functional languages there are monads that is mostly just an interface realization(for example in Scala with flatMap[T] and unit[T] methods) is there are any Java-style interfaces that could be a monad?

Comment: What Java version are you interested in ? `<= 7` or `8` ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu mostly 7, but 8 would be good enough for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with representing monads in Java:

`flatMap` needs to operate on a function that returns the (same) *specific* monad, and Java's type system cannot express that.

`unit` is kind of a static method in Java terms, because it creates a monad *instance* from a generic value. Java 8 has static methods on interfaces, but an *abstract* monad interface cannot know the implementation, so you have to use a factory method somewhere else (or just use a constructor).

As @AlexeyRomanov suggested, you can implement specific monads (e.g. make a `Option` interface), but the *abstract concept of a monad* is not possible in Java. This of course means you cannot create all those useful functions that work for any monad.

Answer (score 7):

No, because monad interface requires so-called higher-kinded types which don't exist in Java. Of course, you can implement many (not all) *specific* monads in Java.